# this.src.replace img src for multiple images

Tags: javascript, replace, image

I want to change the source of an image when hovering over it.

I've managed to do it for one image, by

```
<img id="image1" src="image1-grey.png" onmouseover=colorImage(this) />"
```

And:

```
function colorImage(x){
document.getElementById("image1").src = x.src.replace("grey", "color");
}
```

I have a dozen or so images - all in two versions, grey and color.

Now I guess I could repeat the function above for all the images individually, but there must be a cleaner way.

This is what I figured, but it doesn't work:

```
<img id="image1" src="image1-grey.png" onmouseover=colorImage(image1) />"
```

And:

```
function colorImage(x){
document.getElementById(x).src = this.src.replace("grey", "color");
}
```

This way, I thought, I'd only have one function for all the images. But no. Why not?

Thanks a lot in advance!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since you're passing a reference to the image as a parameter, you don't need to use document.getElementById... you already have it!

```
function colorImage(x){
  x.src = x.src.replace("grey", "color");
}
```

You can continue to call the function using your first way:

```
<img id="image1" src="image1-grey.png" onmouseover=colorImage(this) />
```

Comment: this works beautiful, thanks a lot! so simple, I can't believe it.

Comment: @user1912899 Now you should look into not binding event listeners inline. Google `addEventListener` forthe preferred way of binding listeners.

Answer (score 0):

Looks like your problem is with `image1` in the line below

```
onmouseover=colorImage(image1)
```

it needs to be in quotes like you are passing a string (shown below)

```
onmouseover=colorImage('image1')
```

The way your passing it now you are sending a javascript variable named `image1` (which would be `undefined`) instead of the string name you want `"image1"`