# using thumbnails to change main image using OnClick

Tags: javascript, html, image, onclick, thumbnails

So I have a couple of thumbnails and a big image to left of them, when you click one of the thumbnails I want it to change the main image to which ever thumbnail is clicked, I was thinking of using something like:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
   function changeImage(){
    document.getElementById('image').src='';
   }
</script>
```

Then on the main image:

```
<img src="<?php echo $thumb; ?>" title="<?php echo $heading_title; ?>" alt="<?php echo $heading_title; ?>" id="image"/>
```

and finally on the thumbnails:

```
<img src="<?php echo $image['thumb']; ?>" onclick="changeImage()" title="<?php echo $heading_title; ?>" alt="<?php echo $heading_title; ?>" />
```

Obviously I will need to add something into .src='' but I'm just not sure what, is there something that I can add in there instead of e.g 1.jpg which will select whichever image is clicked?

Comment: This is easily found through Google, and has been asked here a lot already.

Comment: Maybe I not using the right words but I cannot find exactly what I need, the coding seems to be fine that I have so far, I am just not sure what to use for `src` as I need it to be which ever image was clicked.

Comment: Do a Google search for javascript "this" as "this" will be whatever src thumbnail image you click on in your code. Also, you can Google changing an images src via javascript.

Comment: The problem is that if I do that, I am getting completely new code which means replacing what I have already done and I am only a beginner to JS it is a lot of work to take out what I have to put new code in, I was just hoping someone could say, yeah that code will work, you could just add something like `This` in which will make the `src` whichever image was clicked. I don't mean to be lazy but I am still learning and I am trying to get this sorted today if I can.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15079775/this-src-replace-img-src-for-multiple-images

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can pass a reference to the image as a parameter.

```
function changeImage(x){
  document.getElementById('image').src = x.src;
}
```

You can continue to call the function using your first way:

```
<img src="<?php echo $image['thumb']; ?>" onclick="changeImage(this)" title="<?php echo $heading_title; ?>" alt="<?php echo $heading_title; ?>" />
```

Comment: Is there anything I can add to that so that the main image keeps its original size rather then taking on the size of the thumbnail?

Comment: Come on, you could have googled this. Basic HTML question. http://www.w3schools.com/html/html_images.asp Look at the heading HTML Images - Set Height and Width of an Image... Just set it to where it fits in the document

Comment: I know how to set an image height and width, the problem is, when I use the code you gave me, it changes the main image but it also changes it's size to what ever size thumbnail is, I want to keep its original size which may not always be the same depending on what device it is viewed on so I cannot just set width and height to a fixed size ie 500px, I need it to just keep the original size when it changes image.

Comment: If you look here: http://nthwondr.com/index.php?route=product/product&path=59&product_id=61
Click on the thumbnail and you can see the problem.

Answer (score 0):

[TRY THIS DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/Godinall/m3z4w/)

```
<script>
    function updateIMG(e) {
        document.getElementById("preview").src = e;
    }
</script>
```

Comment: For completeness you should include the html from the fiddle in your answer.

Comment: While this link may answer the question, it is better to include the essential parts of the answer here and provide the link for reference.  Link-only answers can become invalid if the linked page changes.

Comment: @mjhm thank you for pointing out, but the most essential part is the js which I provided in my answer?